# Error Propagation And Multiplication by Zero

Tags: error-propagation

So I'm trying to create a python module to be used for Error Propagation just for sake of learning.

let:
$$A=a \pm \delta a$$
$$B=b \pm \delta b$$
As explained [here](https://www.geol.lsu.edu/jlorenzo/geophysics/uncertainties/Uncertaintiespart2.html) Error Propagation of a function as shown
$$y=f(A, B) = A \times B$$
is
$$\delta y= \sqrt{ (\frac{\delta a}{A})^2 + (\frac{\delta b}{B})^2}$$

I understand this part. But what if one of the values is 0.
So let temperature measurements be:
$$T_1=1 \pm 0.5$$
$$T_2=0 \pm 0.7$$

When I multiply these two values I'll get `division by zero` naturally.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Work in Kelvin ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When one of the values is zero, you can't use relative errors. Then use

$$AB\,\delta y=\sqrt{B^2(\delta a)^2+A^2(\delta b)^2}.$$

Comment: Since error for power is calculated as $$A^p = A^p \pm A^p \times p \times \frac{\delta a}{A}$$ I'll still get `division by zero`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I did not answer about powers, did I ?

Comment: So I think I am missing something. Does $$B^2$$ means I raise $$B = b \pm \delta b$$ to the power of 2?
If yes so my problem is I'm getting `division by zero`.
If not. What I'm missing?